# how to setup ssh keys for jenkins to publish via ssh

Tags: jenkins, ssh

Jenkins requires a certificate to use the *ssh* publication and *ssh* commands. It can be configured under `"manage jenkins" -> "Configure System"-> "publish over ssh"`.

The question is: How does one create the certificates?

I have two ubuntu servers, one running Jenkins, and one for running the app.

Do I set up a Jenkins cert and put part of it on the deployment box, or set up a cert on the deployment box, and put part of it on Jenkins?  Does the cert need to be in the name of a user called Jenkins, or can it be for any user?  We don't have a Jenkins user on the development box.

I know there are a number of incompatible ssh types, which does Jenkins require?

Has anyone found a guide on how to set this all up (how to generate keys, where to put them etc.)?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You will need to create a public/private key as the Jenkins user on your Jenkins server, then copy the public key to the user you want to do the deployment with on your target server.

Step 1, generate public and private key on build server as user `jenkins`

```
build1:~ jenkins$ whoami
jenkins
build1:~ jenkins$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa): 
Created directory '/var/lib/jenkins/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
[...] 
The key's randomart image is:
[...]
build1:~ jenkins$ ls -l .ssh
total 2
-rw-------  1 jenkins  jenkins  1679 Feb 28 11:55 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 jenkins  jenkins   411 Feb 28 11:55 id_rsa.pub 
build1:~ jenkins$ cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAlskdjfalskdfjaslkdjf... jenkins@myserver.com
```

Step 2, paste the pub file contents onto the target server.

```
target:~ bob$ cd .ssh
target:~ bob$ vi authorized_keys (paste in the stuff which was output above.)
```

Make sure your .ssh dir has permissoins 700 and your authorized_keys file has permissions 644

Step 3, configure Jenkins

1. In the jenkins web control panel, nagivate to "Manage Jenkins" -> "Configure System" -> "Publish over SSH"
2. Either enter the path of the file e.g. "var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/id_rsa", or paste in the same content as on the target server.
3. Enter your passphrase, server and user details, and you are good to go!

Comment: "Publish over SSH" doesn't exist in my jenkins

Comment: @BigDong it's a plugin, it will appear after you install it

Comment: Whats the plugin?

Comment: @infosecDaemon see https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get `whoami` to return the user jenkins: Once logged in as another user, do `su -s /bin/bash jenkins`. Just doing `su jenkins` won't work because jenkins does not have a shell by default.

Comment: After doing all these steps I was successful but now i am unable to login from local machine thanks

Comment: can we get public key from the graphical interface of jenkins ?

Comment: if you have trouble with jenkins password use sudo su jenkins  ..This will ask only sudo password(root password )

Comment: In addition to this, I also had to manually attempt an SSH connection (or SCP) from the jenkins user to the target machine at least once. It then asked me to verify the remote hostname's authenticity. I typed yes and it was added to the known_hosts file. After that it worked in Jenkins.

Comment: I am new in jenkins and linux cmd. I can do first step but what is target:~ in step 2. :(.

Comment: @SadhaNanda No reason to use two commands that basically do the same thing when one suffices :) Just pass `-s` to `sudo` to gain a shell: `sudo -s -u jenkins`

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to create the SSH keys on the Jenkins server, nor do you need to store the SSH keys on the Jenkins server's filesystem. This bit of information is crucial in environments where Jenkins servers instances may be created and destroyed frequently.

### Generating the SSH Key Pair

On any machine (Windows, Linux, MacOS ...doesn't matter) generate an SSH key pair. Use this article as guide:

- [GitHub: Generating a new SSH key and adding it to the ssh-agent](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise/2.21/user/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) (you can skip the section "Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent")

### On the Target Server

On the target server, you will need to place the content of the *public* key (`id_rsa.pub` per the above article) into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file under the home directory of the user which Jenkins will be using for deployment.

### In Jenkins

#### Using "Publish over SSH" Plugin

Ref: https://plugins.jenkins.io/publish-over-ssh/

Visit: `Jenkins` > `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System` > `Publish over SSH`

- If the private key is encrypted, then you will need to enter the passphrase for the key into the "Passphrase" field, otherwise leave it alone.
- Leave the "Path to key" field empty as this will be ignored anyway when you use a pasted key (next step)
- Copy and paste the contents of the *private* key (`id_rsa` per the above article) into the "Key" field
- Under "SSH Servers", "Add" a new server configuration for your target server.

#### Using Stored Global Credentials

Visit: `Jenkins` > `Credentials` > `System` > `Global credentials (unrestricted)` > `Add Credentials`

- *Kind*: "SSH Username with private key"
- *Scope*: "Global"
- *ID*: [CREAT A UNIQUE ID FOR THIS KEY]
- *Description*: [optionally, enter a decription]
- *Username*: [USERNAME JENKINS WILL USE TO CONNECT TO REMOTE SERVER]
- *Private Key*: [select "Enter directly"]
- *Key*: [paste the contents of the *private* key (`id_rsa` per the above article)]
- *Passphrase*: [enter the passphrase for the key, or leave it blank if the key is not encrypted]

Answer (score 5):

For Windows:

1. Install the necessary plugins for the repository (ex: GitHub install GitHub and GitHub Authentication plugins) in Jenkins.
2. You can generate a key with Putty key generator, or by running the following command in git bash:  `$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C your_email@example.com`
3. Private key must be OpenSSH. You can convert your private key to OpenSSH in putty key generator
4. SSH keys come in pairs, public and private. Public keys are inserted in the repository to be cloned. Private keys are saved as credentials in Jenkins
5. You need to copy the SSH URL not the HTTPS to work with ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

> Username it takes is "jenkins" while setting up the key credentials,
> and then we need to switch to that user (in cli) in order to generate
> key pair to make git connection work.

here are the steps

1. switch to jenkins user

   sudo su - jenkins -s /bin/bash
2. Generate key pair

   ssh-keygen
3. Configure private key in jenkins as described
4. Configure public key on git repository side in deploy key section
5. Test connection, it should work.

**Note**: This steps are for jenkins in local machine , ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: test connection can happen by executing the command: `ssh -T git@github.com` in the context of the jenkins user

Answer (score 0):

After Jenkins upgrade to 2.412 the rsa keys are not working and the plugin file trasfer over ssh is not working.
To get that working generate the ecdsa ssh keys

ssh-keygen -t ecdsa -m PEM -f key_name