# How to deploy a spring boot application jar from Jenkins to an EC2 machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I'm seeing so many different sources how to to achieve CI with Jenkins and EC2 and strangely none seem to fit my needs.

I have 2 EC2 ubuntu instances. One is empty and the other has Jenkins installed on it.
I want to perform a build on the Jenkins machine and copy the jar to the other ubuntu machine. Once the jar is there i want to run `mvn spring-boot:run`

That's is - a very simple flow which i can't find a good source to follow that doesn't include slaves, dockers etc..

Answer (score 0):

AWS Code Deploy lets you use a Jenkins and deploy it on your EC2 instances.

Quick google search gave me this very detailed instruction on [how to setup code pipeline with AWS Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/building-continuous-deployment-on-aws-with-aws-codepipeline-jenkins-and-aws-elastic-beanstalk/).

The pipeline uses `GitHub -> Jenkins -> EC2` flow, as you need it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not familiar with CodeDeploy... is it a free AWS service like micro EC2 instances?

Comment: It is free if you are using EC2 instance, see [Code Deploy](https://aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/faqs/) `Billing` section. If you are running `on-premise` instance, you pay $0.02 per instance update. If you wonder what is `on-premise` instance, see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/instances-on-premises.html).

Answer (score 0):

Set up jenkins to do a build then scp the artifact to the other machine

There's an answer here [how to setup ssh keys for jenkins to publish via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331571/how-to-setup-ssh-keys-for-jenkins-to-publish-via-ssh) about setting up the keys for ssh