# How to clone a bitbucket source code repository using credentials in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins with my Linux box. I have two bitbucket repositories. I am trying to create a Jenkins pipeline.

1. `Repo_A` - Jekinsfile resides here.
2. `Repo_B` - Project's source code resides here.

I want Jenkins to take configurations (`Jenkinsfile`) from `Repo_A`. Also, I want Jenkins to clone my source code to `/some/random/directory`. The credentials are stored in Jenkins, and can be used for both repos.

How can I use multiple repos in a single pipeline? Can somebody please tell me how to do this?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are asking, but normally you specify the `Jenkinsfile` repo and path inside the project configuration, and then your `Jenkinsfile` normally retrieves the source code within the pipeline. Everything it seems you are asking for is normal use case behavior, but with a MCVE someone could probably give you a good answer on how specifically to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ssh authentication, it is suported by Genkins
Here is similar question: [how to setup ssh keys for jenkins to publish via ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331571/how-to-setup-ssh-keys-for-jenkins-to-publish-via-ssh)

To add new repository [image]

[image]